# Terminology for a certain image of an action

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, terminology, group-actions

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ be a left $R$-module. Then for every $\lambda\in R$ the set $\lambda M$ is a submodule of $M$. Does this submodule have name? What is the analogous object in the realm of group actions called (i.e. given a set $X$, a group action $\alpha \colon G\times X \rightarrow X$ and a group element $g\in G$, what is the image of $\alpha(g,–)$ called)?

Comment: For the group action example, the image will just be $X$. Given $x \in X$ we have $\alpha(g, g^{-1} x) = \alpha(1, x) = x$. It's not so simple for rings and modules because $\lambda$ need not be invertible. I don't know of a name for these; they're the module equivalent of principal ideals.